# How to pass fixture when parametrizing a test

Tags: pytest

I am trying to parametrize my test. 
In the setup method which returns a list, I am calling a fixture (app_config).

Now, i want to call the setup so that the list can be used as a parameter values inside the test.

The problem i am running into is that i cannot pass app_config fixture when calling setup in the parametrize decorator.

```
def setup(app_config):
    member = app_config.membership
    output = app_config.plan_data
    ls = list(zip(member, output))
    return ls

@pytest.mark.parametrize('member, output', setup(app_config))
def test_concentric(app_config, member, output):
    ....
    ....
```

Is there an elegant way to pass setup method in the parametrize decorator or any other way to approach this?

Comment: You can't pass fixture to regular python function. You can only pass it to other fixture or test function(or class). 

Your best bet here is to parametrize tests using pytest_generate_test hook to parametrize test. Here is a nice write up about it: https://gist.github.com/kvas-it/13c5b7a484f6bddbb24d10286b7252fa

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, starting with pytest version 4, it has become impossible to call fixtures like regular functions.

- https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly
- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3950

---

In your case I can recommend **not using fixtures** and switch to normal functions.
For example, it might look like this:

```
import pytest


def app_config():
    membership = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    plan_data = [1, 2, 3]
    return {'membership': membership,
            'plan_data': plan_data}

def setup_func(config_func):
    data = config_func()
    member = data['membership']
    output = data['plan_data']
    ls = list(zip(member, output))
    return ls


@pytest.mark.parametrize('member, output', setup_func(app_config))
def test_concentric(member, output):
    print(member, output)
    ....
```

NB! Avoid the **setup()** function/fixture name because it will conflict with pytest.runner's internals.